# Formating Print in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi everyone I have this code :

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1): 
    for j in range(1,n+1):
       print(i*j)
```

the output is this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
2
4
6
8
10
3
6
...
```

but I want to get output like this :

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10
3 6 9 12 15
4 8 12 16 20
5 10 15 20 25
```

I Don't know what to do for print like this.

Comment: for exapmle n=5 , i start 1 to 5 and multiple it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2.x:

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    val = '';
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        sep = '' if(j == 5) else ' '
        val += (str) (i * j) +  sep
    print(val)
```

Python 3.x:

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        print(i*j, end = ' ')
    print()
```

Output:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10
3 6 9 12 15
4 8 12 16 20
5 10 15 20 25
```

Answer (score 2):

Pythons print function automatically print a newline each time the function is called. but you can set what it will print at the end of the line, with adding `end=''` for nothing or for space `end=' '`.
In you case you can try this bellow:

```
n=int(input())

for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        print(i*j, end = ' ')
    print()
```

And the `print` at the end will print a newline after each completion of the first loop.
Finally you output will be like this:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5 
2 4 6 8 10 
3 6 9 12 15 
4 8 12 16 20 
5 10 15 20 25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,n + 1):
    count = 0
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        print(i * j, end = ' ')
        count += 1
        if count % (n) == 0:
            count = 0
            print()
```

I initialized a counter variable and if count mod n is 0, then I assigned the counter to 0 and print a new line.
This is the output

```
5
1 2 3 4 5 
2 4 6 8 10 
3 6 9 12 15 
4 8 12 16 20 
5 10 15 20 25
```